# How do you access a value of an inside-array by a given key name? (Lua)

Tags: lua

I'd like to be able to do this

```
local aoe_radius = userconfig[chosenconfig].radius --chosenconfig is a variable where value could be "small","normal" or "big"
local aoe_damage = userconfig[chosenconfig].damage
```

where userconfig array would something like:

```
local userconfig = {{name="small",radius="5",damage="50"},
{name="normal",radius="8",damage="100"},
{name="big",radius="15",damage="200"}}
```

How do you access radius and damage of a given "name"?

I'd like to avoid writing it like this:

```
if chosenconfig == "small" then
  local aoe_radius = 5
  local aoe_damage = 50
elseif chosenconfig == "normal" then
...
end
```

I'm new in Lua so I welcome redesign of above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
local userconfig = {small={radius="5",damage="50"},
normal={radius="8",damage="100"},
big={radius="15",damage="200"}}

local aoe_radius = userconfig[chosenconfig].radius --chosenconfig is a variable where value could be "small","normal" or "big"
local aoe_damage = userconfig[chosenconfig].damage
```

Note: if chosenconfig isn't "small", "normal" or "big" then `userconfig[chosenconfig]` gives nil, and then `.radius` gives an error (can't access field 'radius' of nil)